# CORS errors with Outlook add-in

Tags: cors, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I see errors being logged in Outlook add-in console due to a CORS issue. It seems like the add-in is attempting to execute a HTTP POST to https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0 and since Access-Control-Allow-Headers did not return valid response, the HTTP call is being blocked by the browser.

Here is the error I see in the console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/Collector/3.0/?qsp=true&content-type=application%2Fbond-compact-binary...' from origin '' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-transaction-source is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Here is the screenshot of the actual HTTP call:
[image]

Comment: Are you seeing this in the rich native Desktop client (Mac / Windows) or in the web client?

Comment: This error is due to an issue with our web application. Sorry for the confusion.